# Checking timezone of email recipients?

Tags: delphi, email, smtp, timezone

Is it possible to check the timezone of email recipients?  An API or code of some sort?  I'm building a mass smtp mailer using Delphi and I want to be able to send only during the office hour timezone of the email recipient.  For development test, I'll be using Gmail SMTP.

Note: I don't have geographic information of the email recipient - I only got the email address to work with.

**EDIT 1:**

By the way, I'm sending to corporate users so they'll probably be using Exchange, Lotus, etc in their own company domain names.

The emails are for official matters such as invoices and orders for offline customers and suppliers.

Comment: Just the thought of someone wanting write a mass smtp mailer makes my skin crawl. Hopefully your intentions are "above-board". If so, then as suggested in [Andy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24079361/224704), have the intended recipients provide the necessary information when the _agree to accept_ the correspondence. This way they can indicate more precisely what time they'd prefer to receive the email.

Comment: Why do you want to only send an email during business hours? The email could also arrive at 3 A.M., but the employee will read it when he enters office. Even if the email server would be shut down over night, the email would arrive, since the sending SMTP server will try it again and again until a limit is reached.

Comment: @rinntech Because they are corporate emails, and I don't want them to get the emails on their Blackberries and smartphones on weekends or after 5pm (office hours).

Comment: That is up to them to decide, not you. If they don't want to receive corporate emails during those hours, they should turn off forwarding on their corporate server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. If you think about it, it makes sense. An e-mail recipient could be potentially anywhere in the world at any time. The only way you could conceivably do it, would be to maintain a list of contacts in a database and store their location. You could then work it out from there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, an idea occurred to me, I could track email reads using tracking image and store the IP address/location in a database. This location can be used the next time I send an email to the same user.

Comment: Unless, of course, your user travels to a different time zone...   Ever checked your email from your phone right after getting off a flight?

Comment: @Joshua: attempts to track client activity are easily disabled/thwarted, so don't rely on it.  And most people's IPs change dynamically over time, unless they own their own domains. And even then, they could be accessing their emails from any number of locations (home, office, phone, café, etc), so there is no guarantee that the IP used one time will be the same IP uses the next time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, there appears to be no way other than accessing a database recorded location.